# How to run a TypeScript file in Heroku Scheduler?

Tags: node.js, typescript, heroku, scheduler

I've got a TypeScript server on Heroku, and I'm trying to schedule a job to run every hour. The app itself works great and serves all the data it needs to, but when I try to run a job through "Heroku Scheduler" it will fail.

This is the command I use to start the job:
`npx ts-node src/scheduler/weatherAlertCheck.ts`

The errors/issues I encounter:

1. I will be prompted with this in the terminal (while I'm testing)

```
Need to install the following packages:
ts-node@10.9.1
Ok to proceed? (y)
```

2. I get an error that seems clearly related to the first issue:

```
/app/.npm/_npx/1bf7c3c15bf47d04/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:859
    return new TSError(diagnosticText, diagnosticCodes, diagnostics);
           ^
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
src/controllers/notifications.ts:3:35 - error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'express'. '/app/node_modules/express/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm i --save-dev @types/express` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'express';`

3 import { Request, Response } from "express";
                                    ~~~~~~~~~
```

So I believe that the scheduler isn't compiling TypeScript before running the command, but I'm not quite sure how to fix that. If I'm wrong, please let me know what else I should try.

Edit: For addition help, here's the look of my package.json

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.17",
    "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.1",
    "@types/node": "^18.14.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.20",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "^4.9.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "npx nodemon",
    "build": "tsc",
    "postinstall": "npm run build",
    "start": "node build/main.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@parse/node-apn": "^5.1.0",
    "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.1",
    "axios": "^1.2.6",
    "body-parser": "^1.20.1",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "fs": "^0.0.1-security",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "knex": "^2.4.0",
    "pg": "^8.8.0",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "^4.9.4"
  }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you forgot `npm i -D @types/express @types/node` because that error is pretty clear: there is no typing for express (it's not a typescript project, nor is Nodejs), so the only thing TypeScript _can_ do is error out.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Those both exist in my dependencies in package.json though. Perhaps I need to run that command remotely on the heroku server? What do you think?

Comment: If you're running your script without first running an npm install as part of the scheduled call, there's very little chance of things working.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, Heroku installs dependencies as part of its build process. I'd argue that TypeScript should be a _dev_ dependency and all TypeScript code should be compiled to JavaScript at build time as well, but if it's declared as a dependency it should be available to the scheduled job. (In this case, `@types/express` is _not_ declared as a dependency so it is _not_ available at runtime.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your start script is done correctly: it runs the compiled *JavaScript* file, not the source TypeScript file.

Your scheduled job should follow the same pattern, e.g. something like

```
node dist/scheduler/weatherAlertCheck.js
```

if `src/scheduler/weatherAlertCheck.ts` gets compiled to `dist/scheduler/weatherAlertCheck.js`.

Note that `ts-node` and `typescript` should probably be declared as *dev* dependencies and not regular dependencies. All TypeScript code should be compiled to JavaScript at build time (dev dependencies are available at build time) and the compiled JavaScript should be used at runtime.

Comment: I love you so much, thank you! This worked perfectly, and made perfect sense. Next time you're in LA, I'm buying you dinner!